# Problem with AMD HD8670M + fglrx driver in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ati, fglrx

I just installed ubuntu 13.10(amd64) in my HP Pavilion 15-e044TX with AMD HD8670M Graphic card. after the first boot, error message was displayed "the system is running in low-graphics mode".

so I entered to shell pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, and then I entered this command below to solve this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

after reboot, login screen was displayed correctly, but after Log in to my user, displayed just a black screen and cursor.

I tried to find a solution much time, but there is no answer to solve my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below tutorial, it worked for me :

http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/fix-catalyst-driver-in-ubuntu-13-04/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Still doesn't work. if I didn't solve this problem, I'm going to downgrade to 13.04 or 12.04...

Comment: I have an Acer Aspire E1-573PG. I ran a fresh install  with the same problem. Did the downgrade solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got my laptop (Acer Aspire E1-572PG with the same graphics card) running smoothy.

Install latest beta of catalyst drivers from AMD, following the [BinaryDriverHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Installing_upstream_drivers_directly_from_AMD.27s_website)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem with installing ubuntu 14.04. and here's additional commands executed in the shell after installation: still low-graphics mode error message displayed after installing 14.04.

`sudo apt-get install fglrx`
`sudo reboot`

and it worked fine, thanks for help even it wasn't useful :P